# If $n \geq 1$ is not prime and $x \in\mathbb{Z}_n$ such that $\gcd(x, n) \neq 1$, prove that $x^{n-1} \bmod n \not\equiv 1$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

> If $n \geq 1$ is not prime and $x \in\mathbb{Z}_n$ such that $\gcd(x, n) \neq 1$, prove that $x^{n-1} \bmod n \not\equiv 1$.

I am not sure why this would be true. So, letting $n$ be a nonprime and $x$ being in $\mathbb{Z}_n$, and with $\gcd(x, n)\neq 1$, both $x$ and $n$ share some common factor. I need to relate this to $x^{n-1}$ having a non-$1$ remainder when divided by $n$, but I don't see any apparent connection that makes this so.

I would really appreciate guidance or clarity, but would not like the problem fully solved for me.

Comment: To get subscripts, use the underline, so a_n gives $a_n$.  To get multicharacter exponents, enclose them in braces, so x^{(n-1)} gives $x^{(n-1)}$.  This works everywhere you need to treat a number of characters as one.  Finally, for mod n! use \pmod {n!} and for gcd use \gcd to get $\pmod {n!}$ and $\gcd$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Thank you both for the help and info on formatting!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ d\mid x,\,\ d\mid n\mid x^{n-1}\!-\!1\:\Rightarrow\:d\mid 1$

Answer (score 1):

Let $d$ be the common factor. Show $d$ is also a factor of $x^{n-1}$. Deduce that $x^{n-1}\not\equiv1\pmod n$.